# scrolling with zoom on a matlab figure

Tags: scroll, zooming, matlab-figure

I plotted a figure in Matlab R2017b using the simple

`[c,h]=contour(x,y,z)`

To zoom on an aspect of the figure, I click on the '+' sign and it enables me to draw a box around the bit of the figure I want to examine further.
Accidentally, I hit some key or key combination which turned the zoom box off but zoomed as I dragged the pointed to the top right, and made smaller as I dragged to the bottom left of the screen. What did I do? and how do I get that back? It applied only to one of the figures I had open.

I've tried right-clicking, and shift/ctrl/alt while clicking and dragging the mouse around. I can't get the figure that does boxes to do the scrolling, and I can't get the scrolling figure to go back to boxes.

Comment: Can you close all the figures and just rerun the script?

Comment: Double-click the figure within that axes area, it will reset the zoom.

Comment: For me, double clicking just resets the view to the original, but I can't change between the swipe-zoom vs draw-a-box-to-zoom.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, closing the figures and rerunning the script just reset the the default to go back to boxes. What did I do to make the box-zoom go away? Or how do I get the swipe-zoom? It would be nice to have control-able options.